# IntelliJ "SBT project import" that creates two modules

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I have a Scala SBT project. When I import the project with IntelliJ, I have two modules to select in the project.

[image]

Why do I have additional "-build" project? Do I have to include the module, or is it OK to ignore the module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2013/07/17/sbt-plugin-nightly-builds/):

> In addition to ordinary modules (which correspond to SBT “projects”), IDEA creates special “SBT” modules, which describe SBT build definitions themselves (.sbt files and Scala files in project directories) in order to provide highlighting, auto-completion and navigation for these files and SBT libraries.

To have the full functionality you should include the module. In the *build.iml files information about the dependencies are stored (amongst other things).

Comment: It's not necessary, it's nice to have though. It is the project for working on the sbt build itself, if you want autocompletion, documentation and source navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Without the module, the build.sbt shows errors in parsing sbt files.

[image]

It's also easy to turn on/off from "SBT projects".

[image]

This is after adding the build module.

[image]